# Google Analytics/React GA: History object is sending increasing numbers of hits with each location change

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-router, react-ga

I've followed what appear to be fairly boilerplate instructions for using React-GA with React Router by listening on the history object for a change of location. Here's the snippet:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    history.listen(location => {
      if (location.pathname.includes('/app')) {
        ReactGA.set({ page: location.pathname }, ['appTracker']); // Update the user's current page
        ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname, ['appTracker']); // Record a pageview for the given page
      } else {
        ReactGA.set({ page: location.pathname }, ['marketingTracker']); // Update the user's current page
        ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname, ['marketingTracker']); // Record a pageview for the given page
      }
    });
  }
```

The problem is every time the location changes, it sends increasing numbers of hits. So if I start at /login it will send 1 hit. Then I change to /signup and it sends 2 hits on /signup. Then I go back to login and it sends 3 hits to /login. And so on. This appears to possibly be an issue with the history object passed down by BrowserRouter, because the same thing happens for console logs. Like I mentioned, the snippet above was copy/pasted almost verbatim from several other blogs referencing standard setup of React GA with React Router, so I'm not sure how to prevent it from sending these duplicate hits.

Answer (score 0):

Found a better way to do this with the `useLocation()` hook in React Router 5.1^:

App.js:

```
let location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      if (location.pathname.includes('/app')) {
        ReactGA.set({ page: location.pathname }, ['appTracker']); // Update the user's current page
        ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname, ['appTracker']); // Record a pageview for the given page
      } else {
        ReactGA.set({ page: location.pathname }, ['marketingTracker']); // Update the user's current page
        ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname, ['marketingTracker']); // Record a pageview for the given page
      }
    }
  }, [location]);
```